# Click listener for ALL buttons

Tags: java, android

I have multiple buttons in my app and I would like to have a single click listener for all buttons in `R.layout.fragment_general`. This is what I have tried:

```java
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general, container, false);
@SuppressLint("ResourceType") ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.layout.fragment_general);
View v;
for(int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
    v = group.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof Button) {
        v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                System.out.println("A button has been clicked");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My app will crash and I get the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int
> android.view.ViewGroup.getChildCount()' on a null object reference

How should it be done correctly?

Comment: It should be `ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.<insert-root-view-id>);`

Comment: @shadow-lad yes! That worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: "*I would like to have a single click listener for all buttons*" - Are you sure about that? This sound an awful lot like a [god object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Comment: @Turing85 yes, I want a simple function (closing the dialog) for all pressed buttons. Or would you set clickListeners for 200 buttons individually?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have 200(!) buttons that all do the same thing, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.ViewGroup.getChildCount()' on a null object reference

It means, that your `group` is null. That happened brcause of this

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType") ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.layout.fragment_general);
```

You should write yours ViewGroups id in findViewbyId(), but not the fragments layout name.